# Running both sendmail and postfix on Ubuntu

Tags: 12.10, postfix, sendmail

I have a requirement to use both Sendmail (MTA) and Postfix on a mailserver.  This is because many of the legacy sendmail.mc rules cannot be migrated to postfix and provide high performance.  So I need to run sendmail for incoming mail and postfix for outgoing on the same server.

However on Ubuntu distros, as soon as I install sendmail -> postfix is removed and vice versa.  Do you have recommendation on overriding this?

Thanks
Vijay